# Sujet non catégorisé

Tags: grammaire, questions, interrogative, sujet

> Lorsque l'interrogation porte sur un **sujet non catégorisé**, il n'est pas possible d'employer **que** ou **quoi** : 
>   - **Qu'est vrai ?* 
>   - **Quoi est vrai ?*

- *Le Grevisse de l'Étudiant*, Cécile Narjoux, De Boeck Supérieur, 2018 (p. 490, 2e remarque)

Que signifie « sujet non catégorisé » ?

Comment: « Qu'est vrai ? » ne se dit jamais ; « Quoi est vrai ? » n'est pas correct non plus mais occasionnellement quelqu'un utilisera cette forme non standard. Il serait utile de fournir le texte qui suscite cette 2e remarque.

Answer (score 4):

Un sujet non catégorisé, c'est un sujet dont on ne connait pas la catégorie, la nature (humain/non humain, animé/inanimé). Exemples :

> *Qui est grand ?*

Le sujet est catégorisé. On sait que la question porte sur une personne.

> *Lequel est vrai ?*

Le sujet est catégorisé. On connaît la liste des choix possibles au moment de la question.

> *<s>Qu'est</s> vrai ?* ou *<s>Quoi est</s> vrai ?*

Le sujet n'est pas catégorisé. La question est ouverte. On dira alors :

> *Qu'est-ce qui est vrai ?*